# Does Java Random have an undocumented nextInt method that takes two parameters?

Tags: java, random, parameters

As far as I can see, this code should not compile or run because Random doesn't have a nextInt method that takes two parameters. But it does run and produces numbers from -5 to 5 inclusive.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomNextIntParameters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a = rand.nextInt(-5, 5); // why does this work?
        while (a >= 0) {
            System.out.println(a);
            a = rand.nextInt(-5, 5);
        }
        System.out.println(a); // prints a negative number
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen C is corret. Thanks! I was looking at Java 8.

Answer (score 7):

## `RandomGenerator#nextInt`

I assume you are on (at least) Java 17 which has introduced the new interface [`RandomGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html) that has a [`nextInt(origin, bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int,int)) method.

As of Java 17, [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) implements that `RandomGenerator` interface, and therefore that `nextInt` method.

As per the description of the method:

> Returns a pseudorandomly chosen int value between the specified origin (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).

For more details, see [*JEP 356: Enhanced Pseudo-Random Number Generators*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/356).

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, I was looking at Java 8. One of my students used this and I thouhgt it was wrong. Guess I need to update my understanding of Java.

Comment: @cuyaken Watching the list of JEPs is a good way to keep up with the major changes to the Java platform. See the list at [*JEP 0: JEP Index*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/0?ref=hackernoon.com). And skimming the Release Notes on each 6-month release of Java is an easy incremental way to keep up. For example, [JDK 18 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/18-relnote-issues.html), specifically its *What's New in JDK 18 - New Features and Enhancements* section.